# Android Version and API Level mismatch

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an (my first) Android app with Visual Studio Tools for Cordova. For testing I bought a cheap Android device which reports to be version 4.4.2 which should be API level 19 compatible.

Minimum SDK version (API Level) for Cordova is 14 or Android 4.0 - 4.0.2.
So I set minimum and target version to 14. Compiling and running the app on the device results in an error:

> Requires newer sdk version #14 (current version is #10)

and

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Afaik, this means, that my app is targeted for api #14 but the phone only supports api level 10. Is that right?

I also run some terminal commands to get the Android version and the api level of the device from adb (I didn't trust the GUI too much after that error happend):

> adb -d shell getprop ro.build.version.release
>
> 4.4.2
>
> adb -d shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
>
> 10

Does anybody else think that is weird?

Is it common among Android devices to state a version but only support a lower API level?

Is there a quick way to check the supported API level on the device itself (e.g. I'm in a shop, looking at a device)?

Or is that a known issue with a "fix"?

Btw, the device is a "Qnet mobile", model "Comic" if somebody is interested :-)

Comment: Set target version to 23 and make sure you have SDK 23 installed and latest sdk-tools too

Comment: @jcesarmobile: doesn't work for obvious reasons: The device is fake. ro.build.version.release had been manipulated by the manufacturer. It was actually a really old android version with a nicer gui skin. Since I usually don't use android devices, I couldn't tell by the look and feel. But I went back to the shop and switched it with a more fancy device. Checked version.release and version.sdk in the shop on my laptop tho - just to be save :-)